# Cannot get pickup directory IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, smtp

I'm getting "Cannot get pickup directory" under IIS 7.5. I've granted privileges to the mail folder to the IIS_IUSRS group. I recall from IIS 6 that I had to use to make some changes to the metabase using ACL tool.

Does the IIS 7.5 also use the metabase? Do I need to do anything with IIS 6 when installing pickup directory?

Thanks for any help/instructions

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an answer. Look forward to any other solutions, explanations..

https://serverfault.com/questions/77766/where-are-the-smtp-settings-saved-in-iis7-win2008

It sounds like getting the directory is the problem. I tried adding the directory directly into my code:

C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup\

But, I'm still getting the error. I'm fairly sure granting the proper privileges in metabase will fix this but would rather not have to bother with that if not required.